# Adding new files with SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a folder named `2016` where I have a bunch of projects. I just added 2 new projects `wap-sprint` and `wap-sprint-2` then I did: `$ svn add --force .` and got this in the console:

```
Marcelo@MacBook-Pro-de-MarceloRS /L/W/D/2016> svn add --force .
A         wap-sprint-2
A         wap-sprint-2/assets
A         wap-sprint-2/assets/css
A         wap-sprint-2/assets/css/legal.css
A         wap-sprint-2/assets/css/index.css
A         wap-sprint-2/assets/img
A         wap-sprint-2/assets/img/index
A  (bin)  wap-sprint-2/assets/img/index/img01.png
A  (bin)  wap-sprint-2/assets/img/index/img02.png
A  (bin)  wap-sprint-2/assets/img/index/img03.png
A  (bin)  wap-sprint-2/assets/img/index/img04.png
A         wap-sprint-2/includes
A         wap-sprint-2/includes/legal1-endoflease.php
A         wap-sprint-2/includes/target1-endoflease.php
A         wap-sprint-2/includes/target2-promotionalupgrade.php
A         wap-sprint-2/legal.php
A         wap-sprint-2/index.php
A         wap-sprint
A         wap-sprint/includes
A         wap-sprint/includes/target2-promotionalupgrade.php
A         wap-sprint/includes/legal1-endoflease.php
A         wap-sprint/includes/target1-endoflease.php
A         wap-sprint/legal.php
A         wap-sprint/index.php
A         wap-sprint/assets
A         wap-sprint/assets/css
A         wap-sprint/assets/css/legal.css
A         wap-sprint/assets/css/index.css
A         wap-sprint/assets/img
A         wap-sprint/assets/img/index
A  (bin)  wap-sprint/assets/img/index/img01.png
A  (bin)  wap-sprint/assets/img/index/img02.png
A  (bin)  wap-sprint/assets/img/index/img03.png
A  (bin)  wap-sprint/assets/img/index/img04.png
```

as you can see, there are 2 new projects, the ones I mentioned above. Now I want to commit those new projects so my coworkers can see them in their computers so I did: `$ svn commit` and I am getting this:

```
Marcelo@MacBook-Pro-de-MarceloRS /L/W/D/2016> svn ci
svn: E205007: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E205007: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
```

If I do `$ svn status` and I get exactly the same output as when I did `$ svn add --force .`

Do you have an idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add` operation worked as intended, that's why the `status` operation is giving the same output. You wouldn't have needed the `--force` though, had you specified the folders you wanted to add:

```
svn add wap-sprint wap-sprint2
```

The changes are not commited yet, and Subversion won't let you commit without an explicit commit message, even if it is an empty one. It is quite apparently complaining that it...

```
(...) Could not use external editor to fetch log message (...)
```

So, as it suggests, either setup an environment variable...

```
(...) consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment (...)
```

which will make it fire up the editor whenever you want to commit but didn't supply any commit message, or simply supply a commit message on the command line:

```
# directly
svn ci -m "added 2 new projects, yadda, yadda"
# alternatively: empty commit message
svn ci -m ""
# alternatively: commit message from file
svn ci -F commitmessage.txt
```